# How to get the value of an input button php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the value of an input-button, because I am trying to set up a "system" where the user can decide between different options and based on what he have chosen an e-mail get sent with the information.
Since I am new to php I am trying to keep it simple.

This is how the input buttons looks like:

```html
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="button" value="VALUE1" />
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="button" value="VALUE2" />  
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="button" value="VALUE3" />
```

They have the same name but different values, I need to get the VALUE attribute and storage it in a php variable.
Since I want to send the information per e-mail.

Comment: So what is the issue??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: You might use a <select> with the different options instead. Otherwise, you could use javascript - set an onclick listener on each of the buttons and update a hidden input with the last clicked button value.

Comment: I can't get the value of the input storaged in a variable

Comment: yeah select wouldn't work in this scenario, but the input button thing could work :)

Answer (score 0):

### via PHP

Wrap the buttons inside a form and change the type into `type=submit`

```
<form action="handle.php" method="POST">
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="submit" value="VALUE1" />
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="submit" value="VALUE2" />  
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="submit" value="VALUE3" />
</form>
```

handle.php

```
<?php

echo $_POST['form-thema'];

?>
```

### via Javascript

I would add an onclick event on each button like so:

**HTML**

```
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="button" value="VALUE1" onclick="choose_value('VALUE1')" />
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="button" value="VALUE2" onclick="choose_value('VALUE2')" />  
<input name="form-thema" class="fwd_btn ipt_btn" type="button" value="VALUE3" onclick="choose_value('VALUE3')" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function choose_value(val) {
    alert(val);
    // You probably need to send this to a php file via ajax

}
```